# How to set max or min values based on selected input

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I have selected input for set max or min values in another input field.

**Selected Input**

```
<select name="SelectedInput" required>
    <option value="a">A</option>
    <option value="b">B</option>
</select>
```

**input field where max value will be set**

```
<input type="number" name="price" id="price_id" min="0" step="0.01" required>
```

**Conditions**

If I select A option, I want to set max value in input field < 5000.

If I select B option, I want to set min value in input field >= 5000.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a free coding service. You're expected to [try to solve the problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). For further information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: What's your question about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selected Input :

```
<select name="SelectedInput" id="prooftype" required>
    <option value="a">A</option>
    <option value="b">B</option>
</select>
```

Input field where max value will be set :

```
<input type="number" name="price" id="price_id" min="0" step="0.01" required>
```

And then include javascript codes :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var selectedopt;

$('#prooftype').change(function(){
   selectedopt=  $(this).val();

   //Add your condition here, and  check the selected option value:
  if(selectedopt== "a")
  {
   //Set input min and max value based on the selected option value.
   $('#price_id').attr('maxlength','4999');
  }
  elseif(selectedopt== "b")
  {
   $('#price_id').attr('minlength','5000');
  }
  // And so on........
})
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: Thank you. I change from attr('maxlength','4999'); and attr('minlength','5000'); to attr('max','4999'); and attr('min','5000');. It's work to me.